# gnatbind: Cannot find: s-stalib.ali

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, ada, gnat

I installed GNAT on my OS X 10.8.5 machine with the following steps:

- Download GNAT GPL from http://libre.adacore.com/download/configurations
- Install with `./doinstall`, accepting all the default options
- Added `/usr/local/gnat/bin` to `$PATH`

After trying to compile a simple hello world example I get this error:

```
$ gnat make hello
gcc -c hello.adb
gnatbind -x hello.ali
gnatbind: Cannot find: s-stalib.ali
gnatmake: *** bind failed.
```

Any idea why this might happen?

PS: `gnat make -a hello` works, but creates tons of files and should not be required as far as i know.

**Edit:** As requested, here is the output of `gnatls -v`

```
GNATLS GPL 2013 (20130314)
Copyright (C) 1997-2013, Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Source Search Path:
   <Current_Directory>
   /usr/local/gnat/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0/4.7.4/adainclude/


Object Search Path:
   <Current_Directory>
   /usr/local/gnat/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0/4.7.4/adalib/


Project Search Path:
   <Current_Directory>
   /usr/local/gnat/x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0/lib/gnat
   /usr/local/gnat/share/gpr
   /usr/local/gnat/lib/gnat
```

Here's an excerpt of the output of `ls -l /usr/local/gnat/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0/4.7.4/adalib/`:

```
total 39224
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     4483 17 Apr  2013 Makefile.adalib
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     1450  3 Jun 18:00 a-assert.ali

...

-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     3178  3 Jun 18:01 s-rpc.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     3778  3 Jun 18:01 s-scaval.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     4908  3 Jun 18:01 s-sequio.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin    10542  3 Jun 18:01 s-shasto.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     6382  3 Jun 18:01 s-solita.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     8265  3 Jun 18:01 s-stausa.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     4919  3 Jun 18:01 s-stchop.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin    14601  3 Jun 18:01 s-stratt.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin    11024  3 Jun 18:01 s-ststop.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     5320  3 Jun 18:01 s-stusta.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     9804  3 Jun 18:01 s-taasde.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     4346  3 Jun 18:01 s-tadeca.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     4234  3 Jun 18:01 s-tadert.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin    12564  3 Jun 18:01 s-taenca.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     6663  3 Jun 18:01 s-taprob.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin    29033  3 Jun 18:01 s-taprop.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin    13719  3 Jun 18:01 s-tarest.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     8863  3 Jun 18:01 s-tasdeb.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin      747  3 Jun 18:01 s-tasinf.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin    13008  3 Jun 18:01 s-tasini.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin    15237  3 Jun 18:01 s-taskin.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     1259  3 Jun 18:01 s-tasloc.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     1710  3 Jun 18:01 s-taspri.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin    11652  3 Jun 18:01 s-tasque.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin    29450  3 Jun 18:01 s-tasren.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     1500  3 Jun 18:01 s-tasres.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin    31332  3 Jun 18:01 s-tassta.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin    11059  3 Jun 18:01 s-tasuti.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     7120  3 Jun 18:01 s-tataat.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     2942  3 Jun 18:01 s-tpinop.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin    11318  3 Jun 18:01 s-tpoben.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin    19570  3 Jun 18:01 s-tpobop.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin    11075  3 Jun 18:01 s-tposen.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     1421  3 Jun 18:01 s-traces.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     3889  3 Jun 18:01 s-tratas.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin    17789  3 Jun 18:01 s-utf_32.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     8312  3 Jun 18:01 s-vaflop.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin      997  3 Jun 18:01 s-valboo.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     1239  3 Jun 18:01 s-valcha.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     1309  3 Jun 18:01 s-valdec.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     2921  3 Jun 18:01 s-valenu.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     1733  3 Jun 18:01 s-valint.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     1345  3 Jun 18:01 s-vallld.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     1807  3 Jun 18:01 s-vallli.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     3841  3 Jun 18:01 s-valrea.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     3078  3 Jun 18:01 s-valuns.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     2863  3 Jun 18:01 s-valwch.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     2157  3 Jun 18:01 s-veboop.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin      535  3 Jun 18:01 s-vector.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     1153  3 Jun 18:01 s-vercon.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     3305  3 Jun 18:01 s-vmexta.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     2474  3 Jun 18:01 s-wchwts.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin      698  3 Jun 18:01 s-widboo.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin      939  3 Jun 18:01 s-widcha.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     2526  3 Jun 18:01 s-widenu.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin      863  3 Jun 18:01 s-widlli.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     1126  3 Jun 18:01 s-widllu.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     1292  3 Jun 18:01 s-widwch.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     1301  3 Jun 18:01 s-wwdcha.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     5682  3 Jun 18:01 s-wwdenu.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     1957  3 Jun 18:01 s-wwdwch.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     1561  3 Jun 18:01 sequenio.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin     1519  3 Jun 18:01 text_io.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin      391  3 Jun 18:01 unchconv.ali
-rw-rwxr--@ 1 padde  admin      389  3 Jun 18:01 unchdeal.ali
```

Interestingly, the requested file `s-stalib.ali` is *not* contained in this directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say `gnatls -v` (or `gnat list -v`), it lists (amongst other things) the object search path: here,

```
...
Object Search Path:
   <Current_Directory>
   /opt/gnat-gpl-2013/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0/4.7.4/adalib/
...
```

What does yours say? is it right? if the files are there, are they readable?

[Later]

OK, you have 9 `s-s*.ali` files, with protection `-rw-rwxr--@` (I'm not sure what the `@` means!), whereas I have 19, with protection `-r--r--r--@`. This looks as though the installation didn't complete for some reason.

When I install GNAT, I use `sudo`: `sudo ./doinstall`. Could that be the difference?

The README says that `doinstall` leaves `install.log` in the current (distribution, I suppose) directory; that might give some clues.

If you do decide to rebuild the library, it's be best to use `Makefile.adalib` in the "installed" `adalib/` directory.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have included the output in my original answer. The files are readable, but i don't see `s-stalib.ali` in there. Is it possible to fix this? Should I copy the `*.ali` files generated by `gnat make -a` to my `adalib` folder?

Comment: I made a backup of my `adalib` folder and copied all the `.ali` files generated by `gnat make -a hello` except for `hello.ali` to my `adalib` folder. While this works, I am not quite sure if this is the correct solution to my problem.

Comment: Reinstalling with `sudo` did the trick. I don't remember whether I used sudo when I first installed gnat but it works now. Thanks!

Comment: Ok now i see how i broke my `adalib` folder. I used `gnat clean` which deleted exactly the files from the `adalib` folder which were missing later on. This in turn happened because i messed up the file permissions. Normally the files would not be writeable, but mine were. Non-writeable files are ignored by `gnat clean`.